# Chinese characters to "xn--[....]"? DNS?

Tags: technology

Sometimes when you directly search some Chinese in certain Chrome browsers you will get something like the following prompt:

> [image]

Here searching 百度 asks:

> Did you mean to go to http://xn--wxtr44c/

What correlation is there between 百度 and "xn--wxtr44c"?

Here's a second example:

> [image]

新浪 prompts:

> xn--efvx5o

What are these codes prompted from Chinese characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Punycode, used in URLs to encode Unicode as ASCII.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Answer (score 0):

The chinese chracters "百度" in web world is the alias of the URL http://xn--wxtr44c/. For a correct setting of browser, the true URL shouldn't appear.